# Creating additional indexes on a table with a columnstore clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, nonclustered-index, columnstore

According to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn934994.aspx#SQL%20Server%202016), a table with a clustered columnstore index can have one or more additional non-clustered indexes. However, when I try to add a non-clustered index on a table with a CCI, I get the error shown in the image below:

[image]

Am I overlooking something, or misinterpreting something? I'm using SQL Server 2016 with SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create additional nonclustered indexes on tables with clustered columnstore indexes, the following script shows this...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T2 (C1 INT NOT NULL, C2 INT, C3 INT);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI ON dbo.T2;
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON dbo.T2 (C2);
GO
```

I have attempted the same thing using SSMS 16.5.3. It is possible that there is a bug in the version you are using (latest is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms ).

Consider creating the script using TSQL rather than the GUI to see if you get the same result.